# PyQt4: variable content not in showing up in QStandardItem

Tags: python, pyqt4, qstandarditem

I'm using PyQt4 and python to parse a csv file, do some calculation and show the result.

if i print the variable, the result shows up correctly. however if i put these variable in QStandardItem, they show up as empty. what am i doing wrong pls?

example below, variables sum and nbr2 in QStandardItem show up as empty, whereas the print is OK.

```
def loadCsv(self, fileName):
    with open(fileName, "rb") as fileInput:
        for row in csv.reader(fileInput):

                            global nbr, nbr2, nbr3, name, sum
                            nbr= 1000
                            nbr2= 20
                            name= row[0]
                            nbr3= float(row[1])
                            sum = int((nbr*nbr2*nb3))
                            print nbr, nbr2, nbr3, name, sum

                            items = [QtGui.QStandardItem(sum),QtGui.QStandardItem(nbr2)]
                            self.model.appendRow(items)

@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
```

Answer (score 1):

`QStandardItem` has multiple constructors. If you pass `int` as an argument, it expects you mean number of rows. If you are to set text, you have to pass `str`.

```
QtGui.QStandardItem(str(sum))
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditem.html#QStandardItem